# Package `listings' has mysterious documentation

Tags: fun

In the `listings` package documentation, there is this:

```
1.4 Seduce to use
```

Is that a programmer's in-joke, or am I missing something?

Comment: It's a pun, most likely, on the pronunciation of 'seduce' and 'use'. Unfortunately, the original author of `listings`, Carsten Heinz, 'vanished' from TeX World, so he would know (unless further maintainers introduced the title of the section later on)

Comment: `printf %b "uce\n" | sed 's/c/s/``? No idea what the connection to that section is? Related to the 'hidden parameter', possibly?

Comment: OK. look at the source for that section in the `.dtx` file and it makes sense. The hidden parameter is the first use of `literate` in the documentation proper, I think.

Comment: The word "Seduce" does not appear in the code, probably a construct.

Comment: @JohnKormylo It is on the 413th line of `listings.dtx`. But I did not get the joke.